# Neo4j db.schema.visualization gives additional recursive relationships

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have created 2 nodes with different types and 2 relationships of the same type between them:

```
CREATE (n1:Node1 {name: 'node1'});
CREATE (n2:Node2 {name: 'node2'});
MATCH (n1) where (n1.name='node1') MATCH (n2) where (n2.name='node2')
    CREATE (n1)-[:connects {num: 7}]->(n2) CREATE (n2)-[:connects {num: 8}]->(n1);
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0EXa.png)

Then I call *db.schema.visualization()* it gives me an additional recursive relationship for each of the node labels. Is this correct behavior or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRU2P.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This non-existent relationship behavior is a known [neo4j issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/9726) that has existed for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [comments in the github issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/9726#issuecomment-990312752) linked by cybersam, try `CALL apoc.meta.graph()` where some fixes have been applied.  This works effectively, though is significantly slower.